# Proof that finite symmetrized relator sets, which are $C'(1/6)$, with equal normal closures are unique

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory, group-presentation, hyperbolic-groups

The following statement is made in the Wikipedia article on [small cancellation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_cancellation_theory) without reference or proof.  Can anyone either provide a proof or point me to a reference with a proof?

The statement:  "If $R$ and $S$ are finite symmetrized subsets of $F(X)$ with equal normal closures in $F(X)$ such that both presentations $\langle X | R \rangle$ and $\langle X | S \rangle$ satisfy the $C'(1/6)$ condition then $R = S$."

Answer (score 1):

[Dehn's algorithm/Greendlinger's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_cancellation_theory#Greendlinger.27s_lemma) give this: By Dehn's algorithm, in a $C'(1/6)$ the shortest trivial words of length greater than $0$ are exactly the shortest relations, so $R$ and $S$ have the same shortest relations. Consider $R_1,S_1$ which are the relation sets with the shortest relations removed.

Claim: $R_1,S_1$ have the same shortest relations. Let $r_0$ be the length of the shortest relations in $R/S$, and let $r_1,s_1$ be the length of the shortest relation in $R_1,S_1$. We can assume without loss of generality that $r_0< s_1 \leq r_1$. Let $w$ be a shortest relation in $S_1$, and apply a step of Dehn's algorithm with respect to the presentation $R$, and note that we can not shorten it with respect to a shortest word in $R$ (that would mean $w$ breaks $C'(1/6)$ in $S$) so we actually use a relation in $R_1$, which means we shorten with a word that is at least as large as $w$. This new reduced word is $v \bar v$ where $\bar v$ is a subword of $w$ with less than half its length, and $v$ is less than half the length of some word in $R_1$.

$|v \bar v|<s_1$, and we can suppose towards a contradiction that $0< |v \bar v|$, hence $r_0\leq|v \bar v|$ since the word is still trivial with respect to $R$. In fact $r_0< |v \bar v|$ since if it were equal, then $v \bar v$ would be a shortest word in $R$, but that would mean one of the factors would be more than $\frac{1}{6} r_0$, contradiction both $S$ and $R$ being $C'(1/6)$. For similar reasons you can not use such a word to reduce by a shortest word in $R$. So we must reduce by a word in $R_1$, and so the reduction can not lead to the trivial word. During the reduction at most $\frac{1}{6} r_0$ can effect the $v$, and more than $\frac{2}{6} r_0$ must cancel out with $\bar v$, so after cancelling with $\bar v$ there is less than $\frac{1}{6}r_0$ of the original $w$ in this new word. We apply Dehn's algorithm again, and we get that we still can't reduce by something of length $r_0$, but if we reduce by something in $R_1$ more than $\frac{1}{6}r_0$ will affect some piece that came from $R_1$ contradicting $R_1$ is $C'(1/6)$.

The above argument can be continued for $R_2,S_2$ and so on, till you exhaust $R$ and $S$. A quick sketch of this is you will have $0<r_0<...<r_n<s_{n+1} \leq r_{n+1}$, you will get a $v \bar v$ which can't be one of lower $r_n$ for the same reasons as the claim, and similarly the rest is pretty much the same, except you need to argue for all lower $r_i$ instead of just $r_0$.

Two standard sources which prove Greendlinger's lemma and Dehn's algorithm are *Combinatorial Group Theory* by Lyndon and Schupp and another standard source is *Geometry of Defining Relations in Groups* by Olʹshanskii.

Comment: This is an interesting idea but why do the two normal closures remain equal after the first step?

Comment: @MoisheCohen Good catch. I edited, and it came out less easy... I feel like there should be a pretty nice van Kampen diagram argument though. ( I think I have an easier argument that just uses that the product of these relations and their conjugates shouldn't really get smaller so something of length $s_1$ should could only be made of $r_0$'s or one $r_1$. )